# Square tile navigation unity

Tags: unity, path-finding

I'm looking to generate a grid style navigation system in Unity. I have created a map in Tiled and am unsure how to continue considering the tiles will have different properties.

The closest example I can think of  would be something akin to the Fire Emblem series of games, in which sprites navigate across the terrain using square tiles.

Any advice on how to achieve this, preferably without paying for a unity asset, would be greatly appreciated. If it helps, I'm hoping to run this on a mobile device.

Here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CayKDbKFTb4).

Comment: I have no idea what fire emblem is or the style of movement it uses... Any chance you could post some images or a link to a video to see it in action?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Here's an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CayKDbKFTb4). I am trying to emulate the movement of the sprites across the maps and not so much the battle scenes during the fights. If it helps, I'm aiming to run the game on a mobile device.

Comment: Go through these bunch of tutorials and you would have more clarity about how to go about it : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbghT7MmckI4qGA0Wm_TZS8LVrqS47I9R